# Change the firebase security role

Tags: android, json, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following JSON file structure in Firebase realtime database.
I want to make my role, if the **name** and the **number** are empty, don't read the data, write to firebase is okay for now...
Does the code I wrote is correct? I don't know how to target a specific branch in my tree (I'm a beginner). It throughs an error says Unknown variable '$name'.

Here is my code:

```
{
 "rules": {
    "users": {
        "uid": {
          "name":{
            ".read": "$name !== null",
            ".write": true
         }
      }  
    }   
  }
}
```

Here is my sniped original code.

```
users
 4hUNfg6xhiZ8ZTVQVFOYeFHL2ME3
  blood_Group: "A+"
  city: "الموصل الايسر"
  donor: true
  email: "a07503240115@gmail.com"
  gender: "ذكر"
  mobile: "07503240115"
  name: "أحمد ابراهيم"
  password: "a07503240115"
  uid: "4hUNfg6xhiZ8ZTVQVFOYeFHL2ME3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only some predefined variables that you can use to writes rule like:

`auth` - which contains user authentication info

`data` - contains data under current tree.

So you can't access the fields like database like variables.

Here's what I am assuming you want - user should only be able to `read` from `users/$uid`, if the `name` and `mobile` fields of that user object is not empty.

Here's how you do it:

```
   {
     "rules": {
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
              ".read": "data.child('name').val() != null &&  data.child('name').val().length > 0 && data.child('mobile').val() != null &&  data.child('mobile').val().length > 0",
              ".write": true
             }
          }  
        }   
    }
```

This will allow read access to particular user object only if both of **name** and **mobile** are NOT null and NOT empty.

Comment: Thank you for your code @Susheel. I tried your code but doesn't work. I even change the '&&' to '||' nothing change. I don't know where is the problem still.

Comment: @AhmedMostfa_89 Are you getting any error message while publishing rules? if yes please share it.

Comment: I followed the exact code you shared. It says _read denied_ . The simulation snapped:                                                                                                       Type read
Location /users/uid/name/"أحمد ابراهيم"
Data null
Auth null

Comment: @AhmedMostfa_89 Thats not a valid path. You can only refer to documents not fields. A valid path is - **users/4hUNfg6xhiZ8ZTVQVFOYeFHL2ME3** . Try this and let me know.

Comment: It works now. Thank you, but when I published it, it doesn't work in my mobile. can I send you the play store app link? There must be smthg wrong. Well, the app searches for blood type and city, if data found at the firebase side (based on blood type and city), it will show me all the results. But as you know some users put their info without phone number and name. I still face the same problem.

Comment: According to your requirement, the data seems useless if it doesn't have Name or Mobile number. So, it is best to make those fields as mandatory fields in the form if you haven't already. And please share the code you are using for searching and screenshot/video of app while searching